# c# - Check if object was converted when put into a list?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I am making a game where there are squares (sectors) generated to make a path for a ball to go.  There are two types of sectors: Sector and Presector.  They are all put into a list of type Sector.  How would I check to see if a specific sector in that list was actually a Presector before it was put in?

BTW: Presector is a child class of Sector.

I looked all over the place and couldn't find anything.  The **as** keyword isn't working for me, and **Type.IsAssignableFrom** isn't either.  EDIT: **is** will not work either, since that just checks if an object is that type.

SAMPLE CODE TIME!

```
List<Sector> sectors = new List<Sector>();
sectors.Add(new Sector());
sectors.Add(new Presector());
```

Now, we have a list full of two sectors.  The second one was casted.  How do I find that out using code?

Comment: It would help to include some code. It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do, or what you did with `as` and `IsAssignableFrom` that didn't work.

Comment: Agreed. What about `as` didn't work?

Comment: I added a bit of sample code now.  Sorry I can't explain this well!

Comment: add some code that is producing some values/output that you consider to be wrong or confusing instead of just saying that something "isn't working"

Comment: When I run your sample code, with a simple `Console.WriteLine(sect is Presector)`, it returns `false true`. So your sample code does not appear to line up with your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (objectFromList is Presector)
    // Code here..
```

Comment: That didn't work either.  It makes unreachable code.  The object from the list would have been casted to become a Sector, so **is** does not work.  I want to see if that sector had been casted to be a Sector and originally was a Presector.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that was working because I didn't realize you can't do if (!objectFromList is Presector)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Sector> sectors = new List<Sector>();

sectors.Add(new Sector());
sectors.Add(new Presector());
sectors.Add(new Sector());

Presector ps = new Presector();
sectors.Add(ps);

// this returns an array with one element
var x = sectors.OfType<Presector>().ToArray();

// this returns true (the second element IS a Presector)
var hasPresector = sectors.Any(s => s is Presector);

// this returns true (the presector is present in the list)
var containsPs = sectors.Contains(ps);
```

What's the problem with the 'is' keyword?

Comment: How did you get the List.OfType?

Comment: How would I check if a specific sector in the list is a Presector?

Comment: I'm just doing sectors.Add(presectorVariable);

Comment: by using the contains method (look @ example)

Comment: Wait, I found a weird thing.  I was getting unreachable code because I was doing if (!sector is Presector)  It works fine if I do if (!(sector is Presector))

Comment: the exclamation mark needs to be outside the brackets